# DropDownList with Class values

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

My Class:

```
public class Transport
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual Class.CarModel Modelis { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
 public class CarModel
 {
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual string model_name { get; set; } 
 }
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using web_nt.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Npgsql;

namespace web_nt.Controllers
{
    public class TransportController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
            {
                //ICriteria.SetMaxResult();
                var index = session.Query<Transport>().ToList() ;
                return View(index);
            }

        }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Transport item)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                  //  item.owner = item.Vartotojas.Id;
                    //item.travel_type = item.Vartotojas.name;
                    session.Save(item);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
        {
            var item = session.Get<Transport>(id);
            return View(item);
        }

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Transport item)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
            {
                var tabletoUpdate = session.Get<Transport>(id);
                tabletoUpdate.model = item.model;                    
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(tabletoUpdate);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
        {
            var item = session.Get<Transport>(id);
            return View(item);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
        {
            var item = session.Get<Transport>(id);
            return View(item);
        }
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, Transport item)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Delete(item);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I want to make `DropDownListFor` for Class `Modelis`. You send value `Id` and show value `model_name` in Create View. How can I do it?
Controller users Nhibernate. Nhibernate is where mapping is done. But bassicly all functions and Views management is here.

Comment: Enumerators. But It didn't helped much since I cant declare two models in a view.

Comment: I don't make any sense what you try to do.But i thinks you have to try second dropdown fill on the basis of first according to pass ID, so you try to that using jquery.

Comment: I get CarModels by mapping with nhibernate from SQL database

Comment: I just want to create dropdownlist that could get value from CarModel.Id and Text from CarModel.model_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create [`SelectListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)s:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCarModels()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var car in GET_CARS())
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = car.Id.ToString(),
                Text = car.model_name
            });
    }

    return list;
}
```

This you then pass as the second parameter to `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modelis, LIST_FROM_ABOVE)
```

Comment: this should be in controller or class?

Comment: Where you see it fits (but NOT in the view). I tend to put this in the model class and then use it like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modelis, Model.GetCarModels())`.

Comment: and GET_CARS should I write it as a new function? or what it is?

Comment: There you get your cars you want in the selection. As you did not show how you do that I can't help you there, but thats something like `db.CarModels.Where(...).ToList()`. If you put it directly in there or in a separate method you need to descide on your own, which makes more sense...

Comment: I get it from TransportController. But as long as I tried I can't access functions from there. And there is nothing else in class'es either

Comment: Show us that controller (edit it to the question) and we may can help you there...

Comment: CarModel is mapped using Nhibernate. Carmodel values are sent to Transport.Modelis

Comment: But where do you get the possible values for that property? `Transport.Modelis` only contains the current one and with one item you can not fill a drop-down...

Comment: var index = session.Query<Transport>().ToList(); gets the values in list.

Comment: I think we need to clarify: Do you want your drop-down to contain different `Transport` to choose from (if so, what Id - the Id of `Transport` or `CarModel`?) to select it for something else or do you want a drop-down of `CarModel`s to select them for one `Transport`?

Comment: I have Create view, which contains information about transport(car). One of the fields is Model(Like BMW 320?) And I want that when I create a transport(car) I choose from Model list and I get the value in. Nhibernates lets me collect info about models from database by mapping it to main class. But still it is the same, all information about car model is in Modelis variable.

Comment: I have managed to suceed in giving the data where I need. Now problem is to sending it from View to field. New topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262539/dropdownlist-via-viewbag

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version might be:

```
public SelectList GetCarModels()
{
    return new SelectList(GET_CARS(), "Id", "model_name")
}
```

And in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modelis, CarModels)
```