# DropDownListFor via ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, controller

This is a follow-up to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257975/dropdownlist-with-class-values).

My controller

```
using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
{
    var index = session.Query<Transport>().ToList();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var car in index)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() 
          { Text = car.Modelis.model_name, Value = car.Modelis.Id.ToString() }); 
    }
    ViewBag.Modeliai = new SelectList(items, "Id", "model_name");
    return View(items);
}
```

View is something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Modelis.model_name, ViewBag.Modeliai)
```

And something is wrong with View code. How do I put the ViewBag value to the drop-down-list?

Comment: What is the result? Exception or wrong output? Or is the post-back the problem? P.S.: You "doubled" the `SelectListItem` generation - you can just use the `for`-loop and assign `items` to `ViewBag.Modeliai` or simply `ViewBag.Modeliai = new SelectList(index, "Id", "model_name");` (I like the first one better, as it is strongly typed).

Comment: I get this:  CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<web_nt.Models.Transport>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure WHAT you actually want to select, but following should work:

```
using (ISession session = NHIbernateSession.OpenSession())
{
    var index = session.Query<Transport>().ToList();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var car in index)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() 
          { Text = car.Modelis.model_name, Value = car.Modelis.Id.ToString() }); 
    }
    ViewBag.Modeliai = items;
    return View(index);
}
```

and

```
foreach (var transport in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => transport.Modelis.model_name, ViewBag.Modeliai)
}
```

Comment: I get this: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'web_nt.Models.Transport' because 'web_nt.Models.Transport' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Are you returning the `List<Transport>` in the `View(...)`?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: The `session.Query<Transport>().ToList()` should get you that and if you then return `View(index)` as in my example it should be that way...

Comment: where should I implament this?

Comment: so.. where to add it?

Comment: My example shows everything you need. If you do it that way you should not get the exception from your first comment...